# Marginal effect of interaction variable in probit regression using Stata

Tags: stata

I am running a probit regression with an interaction between one continuous and one dummy variable. The coefficient is displayed in the regression output but when I look at the marginal effects the interaction is missing.

How can I get the marginal effect of the interaction variable?

```
probit move_right c.real_income_change_percent##i.gender

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -345.57292  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -339.10962  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -339.10565  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -339.10565  

Probit regression                                 Number of obs   =        958
                                                  LR chi2(3)      =      12.93
                                                  Prob > chi2     =     0.0048
Log likelihood = -339.10565                       Pseudo R2       =     0.0187

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                         move_right |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         real_income_change_percent |   .0034604   .0010125     3.42   0.001      .001476    .0054448
                                    |
                             gender |
                            Female  |   .0695646   .1139538     0.61   0.542    -.1537807    .2929099
                                    |
gender#c.real_income_change_percent |
                            Female  |  -.0039908   .0015254    -2.62   0.009    -.0069805   -.0010011
                                    |
                              _cons |  -1.263463   .0798439   -15.82   0.000    -1.419954   -1.106972
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


margins, dydx(*) post

Average marginal effects                          Number of obs   =        958
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Pr(move_right), predict()
dy/dx w.r.t. : real_income_change_percent 1.gender

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           |            Delta-method
                           |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
real_income_change_percent |   .0002846   .0001454     1.96   0.050    -4.15e-07    .0005697
                           |
                    gender |
                   Female  |  -.0102626   .0207666    -0.49   0.621    -.0509643    .0304392
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems strange to me. You asked about a dummy-dummy interaction, but your example involves continuous-dummy interaction.

Here's how to do either one:

```
webuse union, clear

/* dummy-dummy iteraction */
probit union i.south##i.black grade, nolog
margins r.south#r.black

/* continuous-dummy iteraction */
probit union i.south##c.grade
margins r.south, dydx(grade)
```

You should try to reproduce these by "hand" (using differences of `predict`s) to understand what the margins command is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks!
Sorry. Didn't proofread enough.
I actually have cases of both dummy-dummy and dummy-continous and your answer really helps!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a question specific to a piece of software (Stata), hence the close votes, but there is a statistical question lurking here: What would a marginal effect of an interaction effect look like?

Such marginal effects are not trivial, and tend to depend strongly on the values of the other covariates, see [this article](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0063). Often this marginal effect is so variable that it makes no sense to try to summarize it with one number. In my opinion, this is a major weakness. To the extend that in general I tend to prefer using logistic regression and interpret the interaction term as a ratio of odds ratios, see [this article](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0194).

Comment: How would you go about finding the difference in effect of `real_income_change_percent` based on gender?